# Cannot find modules

Tags: angular, modulenotfounderror

I am progressing on Google's Tour of Heroes, half an hour to get the list of heroes with the details of one besides, then a quarter of an hour to split the heroes component.

But then, without I know why, on another repetition, I get 5940 errors of type TS2792, "Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/BehaviorSubject'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?"

Well in fact, I have let the default options, and in the other repetitions it runs quite good.

I saw advise
`{ "compilerOptions": { "moduleResolution": "node" } }`

and I saw this was what I found in config.json (well today it is much more simple, there is no config.json).

Well, there is the solution to redo everything from start, but understanding what happens could be more ... interesting.

Any clue about what is different this time, compared to the tens of times when everything runs nice?

Comment: Do you import it as `import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';`?

Comment: You should share some code, at least on the component that is triggering this error.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question, but I would recommend using the new documentation of angular. The old one does not always follow best practices. https://angular.dev/

Comment: I noticed that angular.dev was proposed when presenting a new version of Angular two weeks ago. Is it a good idea to go back and forth between angular.io and angular.dev for the same version?

Comment: Just use angular.dev.